# Which one of these is better for short audio input in iPhone- .caf or .wav?

Tags: iphone

I am making a simple application for iPhone, and I want to enter a short audio file on an object click. Which of .caf and .wav would be better?

I am building a simple application in [Cocos2d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocos2d) in which balloons produce a pop sound when clicked. What are the memory issues with both sound versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need specific [Core Audio Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio_Format) features, then [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) has more universal support (and it would be my default choice for that reason).

Core Audio Format basically functions as a container for other audio file formats, including WAV. Core Audio Format has many great features, but it's not evident from the description that you need any of these.

---

In response to a deleted comment, which was moved to the question:

I can't speak for Cocos2d specifically, so I will write about the file formats in general: WAV does not use data compression. CAF may. If it is a short sound file, you probably don't *want* data compression (because it requires a good amount of processing to convert to [LPCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_pulse-code_modulation) for playback). If you play the pop often, then you will want to hold onto an uncompressed version of the audio data for easy processing. 1 second will require `44100 * 2` bytes at CD quality in memory (per channel).

For a short sound file such as a balloon pop, a 16 bit WAV file sounds ideal. In that sense, the memory difference should not be a deciding factor. If you have a lot of audio files, or long audio files to load into memory, then the situation changes. For now, I don't consider memory to be a problem in your case. Since CAF is a container, its uncompressed representation will be nearly identical (the difference will be a little more header data in the CAF).

Comment: The comment got deleted :( BTW your suggestion was helpful. Finally i am going with wave file.

Comment: No problem - I saw it has moved to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

A CAF file is a basically **Core Audio Format**. So it is well suited for the Apple frameworks. The best advantage of CAF over WAV is while recording when you can have files more than 4 GB and also in CAF you don't need to update the WAV header after each packet recording.

Anyway, I assume you don't need these features related to CAF. And as Justin said, I do believe that **WAV will be the better option** as you can have more support for WAV than the CAF format.